# How to use bootstrap accordion code in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I just copied the code of bootstrap accordion from bootstrap components https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/ ,

Expected that there will be a dropdown but it is not there
Do not want to use the react bootstrap component  https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/

```
import React from "react";

export default function about(){
 

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div className="accordion-item">
    <h2 className="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button className="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" className="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div className="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="accordion-item">
    <h2 className="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <button className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <div className="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="accordion-item">
    <h2 className="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <button className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <div className="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>  
    
    
    
  );
}
```

I also imported `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in app.js

but on rendering only the top accordion is showing cannot drop down other accordion.
Noob at react :)

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install Bootstrap JS...

`npm install bootstrap@latest --save`

Then the `data-bs-` attributes will work to activate the Accordion Collapse component.

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/GOoSEQpVRq#)

Comment: I know this is a bit old but that's a good demo sample, it helped me.

Comment: are the any way if I don't use npm bootstrap lib?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have imported `bootstrap.js` or not.
but first install the bootstrap package from npm with this commmand:

`npm install bootstrap@latest --save`

Then import the bootstrap css and JS in your application. As I can see to work accordian it needs bootstrap.js should be included. Include below code in your react application.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
```

Note: I will suggest to use useEffect hook to import bootsrtarp JS, but to try working above method also work.

```
useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);
```

Here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-dawn-43lx6e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to install Bootstrap, wich you didn't do it seems.

```
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.1
```

Then in the file where you want to use the component from Bootstrap, you must import the component, like so:

```
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'
```

Note: Replace Accordion by whatever other component you would need.

Then in your code you can call this component like so:

```
   <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

You can learn more on this topic here: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your code with bootstrap without react bootstrap component then copy the following lines into the index.html file head which will be available in react folder -> public -> index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This links the bootstrap stylesheet to your react app.
Read more at [bootstrap getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: it's not working because we need to import boostrap js file